# How can I compare two words in the Russian corpus?

Tags: resources

This question is not Russian language-related strictly speaking, but I think it's useful for a lot of people using the language. I wonder if it is possible to use the [ruscorpora.ru](http://ruscorpora.ru/) website to build the comparative word usage frequency distribution by year for two (or more) words. I have found the [user manual](http://ruscorpora.ru/instruction-main.pdf), but couldn't find the answer there.

For example, I'd like to compare the words скакалка and прыгалки, i.e. have these two plots — [first](http://search.ruscorpora.ru/plot.xml?smoothing=3&stat=gr_created_&env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%EF%F0%FB%E3%E0%EB%EA%E8) and [second](http://search.ruscorpora.ru/plot.xml?smoothing=3&stat=gr_created_&env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%F1%EA%E0%EA%E0%EB%EA%E0) — plotted in the common axes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for juxtaposition-ed plots, you can do this:

[search-beta.ruscorpora.ru/ngram.xml?mode=main&t1=скакалка&t2=прыгалки&start=1800&end=2010&smoothing=3](http://search-beta.ruscorpora.ru/ngram.xml?mode=main&t1=%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0&t2=%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8&start=1800&end=2010&smoothing=3)

You can start by clicking "графики" on the home page of ruscorpora.